# Angular iterate and create new rows

Tags: angular

In the array below, assume the first number indicates row, the second column. How would you iterate over the array and break (new div) for each row?

```
array = ['1:1', '1:2', '1:3', '2:1', '2:2', '2:3', '3:1', '3:2', '3:3'];

<ng-container *ngFor="let item of array;">
    <div class="row">{{item}}</div> // div for every row
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this below concept for doing this.

**Note :**

1 Use Pipe instead of doing this calculation in component. I just added in component to give you an idea

**.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

  dataArray = ['1:1', '1:2', '1:3', '2:1', '2:2', '2:3', '3:1', '3:2', '3:3'];
  newArr = []
  preRow = 0
  preCcolumn = 0
  localArr = []

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataArray.forEach((data, i) => {
      let array = data.split(':')
      let row = array[0]
      let column = array[1]
      if (this.preRow === +row) {
        this.localArr.push(`${row}:${column}`)
      } else {
        if (this.localArr.length === 0) {
          this.localArr.push(`${row}:${column}`)
        } else {
          this.newArr.push(this.localArr)
          this.localArr = []
          this.localArr.push(`${row}:${column}`)
        }
      }

      this.preRow = +row
      this.preCcolumn = +column

    })
    this.newArr.push(this.localArr)
  }
}
```

.html

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let row of newArr; let i = index">
  <div class="column" *ngFor="let value of row;">
    {{value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

working link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jruymf